# Request - post many files

Tags: python, python-requests

**in html:**

```
   <form action="/addCar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   many inputs (text, email, etc)

   <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="files[]">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="files[]">
   </li>

  </form>
```

How to send many files (python requests)? I use:

```
    files = {
        'files[]': open('img/1.jpg', 'rb'), 
        'files[]': open('img/2.jpg', 'rb')
    }
session = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36'}
r = session.post(site, car_dict, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, files=files)
```

But it upload only `2.jpg`. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to send 5 different requests to accomplish this, you can't send them all at once.

Comment: so, I can send only one file?

Comment: I think so, `request.session`  doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the names. Make it different:

```
files = {
    'file1': open('img/1.jpg', 'rb'), 
    'file2': open('img/2.jpg', 'rb')
}
```

Or put it in a list:

```
files = {
    'files': [open('img/1.jpg', 'rb'), open('img/2.jpg', 'rb')]
}
```

Comment: `files = {
    'files': [open('img/1.jpg', 'rb'), open('img/2.jpg', 'rb')]
}` - `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Try the first one then, i don't know what kind of request are you making.

Comment: if first - no images upload

Comment: Can you explain what kind of request are you making and what kind of request is the server expecting?